# Reusing Android Lock Pattern

Tags: android

I am writing a application and it should be protected with a password. Instead of building a new one, Is it possible to use the Android's Pattern lock screen from application with different patterns?

Comment: [check this lock pattern library.](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-lock-pattern/)

Answer (score -1):

First you have to setup the Pattern Lock by going into setting manually .
then you can receive the events using code below .
  `

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DemoDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
        static final String TAG = "DemoDeviceAdminReceiver";

        /** Called when this application is approved to be a device administrator. */
        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onEnabled(context, intent);
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.device_admin_enabled,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onEnabled");
        }

        /** Called when this application is no longer the device administrator. */
        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onDisabled(context, intent);
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.device_admin_disabled,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onDisabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onPasswordChanged(context, intent);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPasswordChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onPasswordFailed(context, intent);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPasswordFailed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onPasswordSucceeded(context, intent);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPasswordSucceeded");
        }



}
```

For Complete understanding please read this . [Complete Code And Explaination](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1291/android_device_policy_administration_tutorial)

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Sorry As there was A lot code and explanation so i referred you some links. try above and tell me if you need any help