# Using the Android Pattern Lock screen as a LOG-in to my android application

Tags: android

I am making an Android application and I want dat the entry into the application should be protected by keeping the pattern lock screen as a LOG-in.
Is it possible to use the Android pattern lock screen as a Log-in to our own made applications...
If possible HOW...?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of very similar questions to this one already, e.g.
[Reusing Android Lock Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062532/reusing-android-lock-pattern)
[Android App and Pattern Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172551/android-app-and-pattern-lock-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/) project useful. Simply use the code to create pattern password

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, LockPatternActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(LockPatternActivity._Mode, LockPatternActivity.LPMode.CreatePattern);
startActivityForResult(intent, _ReqCreatePattern);`

and in onActivityResult you get your password.